# How to print all java compiler output as it happens?

Tags: debugging, netbeans, maven, compiler-errors, javac

If I build the project with maven it'll fail but with fewer prints than if I compiled with javac directly. Debugging with NetBeans it would help if I could see the print outs as they happen, rather than going by commenting.

This is my config:

```
> <plugin>
>                 <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
>                 <version>2.3.2</version>
>                 <dependencies>
>                     <dependency>
>                         <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
>                         <artifactId>plexus-compiler-javac</artifactId>
>                         <version>1.6</version>
>                     </dependency>
>                 </dependencies>
>                 <configuration>
>                     <source>1.6</source>
>                     <target>1.6</target>
>                     <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
>                     <compilerId>javac</compilerId>
>                     <verbose>true</verbose>
>                     <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
>                 </configuration> ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The [example](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/pass-compiler-arguments.html) on the maven site looks different form what you have used. It has a "compilerArgument" or "compilerArguments" tag. Maybe that is the issue?

Comment: There is redundancy in the configuration: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#showWarnings.

Answer (score 0):

It seems impossible for now... Maven compiler plugin uses plexus-compiler-javac wrapper library internally to invoke javac. plexus-compiler-javac parses compiler output and mangles it so that only errors and warnings are left...

The idea behind plexus-compiler-javac library is that it implements standard interface and same interface can be used to access native C++ compilers or C# compiler...